# openGLView reload after going to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I have created an application, with Cocos2D. Really good framework.
My problem is, sometimes when I put my app in background (multitasking), and go back after a few seconds, it gives me a black screen when I go to another scene and try to reload the past running scene.

I have seen that it could be explain by the openGLView which reload some images when the app was put in background and we come back on it.
First of all, is it true ?

If yes, how to stop the current glview, and load a new one ? I have tried this code :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)
                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                   depthFormat:0
                   preserveBackbuffer:NO
                   sharegroup:nil
                   multiSampling:NO
                   numberOfSamples:0];

CCDirectorIOS*director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director_ setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeAll];
director_.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
[director_ setDisplayStats:NO];
[director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
[director_ setView:glView];
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];              
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];  
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.1 scene:[Menu scene]]];
```

My menu scene is running, but the touch events on the screen are not well received.

Have you got some issues?

Comment: which version of cocos is this? It looks like the outdated v2.

Comment: I don't know where I could check my cocos2D version

Comment: look at the console when you start, you should see a log line like:               cocos2d: Cocos2D-Swift version 3.2.1

Comment: not in my version, should be too old

Comment: open cocos2d.m file, and version is printed to the log since the past 5+ years so just look closely (scroll up)

Comment: V2.1, this bug is corrected in the 3rd version ?